# Mac run python script with double click

Tags: python, macos, automator

I'm trying to make an automator application to run a python script so I can double click the icon and start the script.

it doesn't give me an error but it does nothing.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Running Script

python /Desktop/test.py

echo Script ended
```

[image]
I also tried with a Shell script .sh with the same code.

it was working before with the .sh until I updated to Mac OS Ventura.
I also installed anaconda and python, but not sure how to point to anaconda environment.

any help would be great
Thank you

Comment: What is the absolute path of your py file? Are you sure that it starts with just /Desktop/? Because my desktop path looks like /Users/myname/Desktop/

Answer (score 0):

A shell of Automator has different `PATH`, `setopt`, and other values from your shell in terminal. Therefore the script in your Automator won't work exactly the same in your shell.

## To make it work, you need to use an absolute path of the `python` command.

Run this command in your terminal to get the absolute path.

```
which python
```

After, fix `python` in your script with the previous result.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Running Script

/Absolute/path/somewhere/python /Desktop/test.py

echo Script ended
```

## To debug with showing a window of the script result

Add "Run Applescript" in your automator app with the code below.
It's not perfect but useful.

Also, in your picture, you can see the result by click the `Results` button.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    display dialog input as text
end run
```